# Joins are erroring with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to join multiple tables together and only get some of the fields

here's my sql code:

```
SELECT t1.match_id, t1.provider_id, t1.visible, t2.match_type, t3.class_num, t3.location_id, t4.prov_name, t6.city_name
    FROM match AS t1 
        JOIN umtc_class AS t2
            on t1.match_id = t2.match_id
        JOIN abroad_class AS t3
            on t1.match_id = t3.match_id
        JOIN provider AS t4
            on t1.provider_id = t3.provider_id
        JOIN location AS t5
            on t3.location_id = t3.location_id
        JOIN location AS t6
            on t5.city_id = t6.city_id
```

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match AS t1

```
    JOIN umtc_class AS t2
        on t1.match_id = t2.match_id
```

' at line 2

I keep messing around with it but I can't get anywhere....any ideas has to why it isn't working?

Comment: Probably isn't your syntax error, but you probably didn't want to do this (underneath t5 join): on t3.location_id = t3.location_id

Comment: Also, did you mean to join the location table twice?

Comment: It tends to be easier to spot issues like this if your table aliases have meaningful names, rather than t1, t2, t3, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATCH is a function name and thus a reserved word. Try using the fully qualified table name with the database name prepended:

```
SELECT ...
FROM mydb.match AS t1
```

Comment: After the help from M.Ali to get my tables selected right (it's been one of those days), this was the problem that was really happening. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
FROM match AS t1 
    JOIN umtc_class AS t2
        on t1.match_id = t2.match_id
    JOIN abroad_class AS t3
        on t1.match_id = t3.match_id
    JOIN provider AS t4
        on t1.provider_id = t3.provider_id   --<-- This ON clause should have t4 in it
    JOIN location AS t5
        on t3.location_id = t3.location_id   --<-- This ON clause should have t5 in it
    JOIN location AS t6
        on t5.city_id = t6.city_id
```

Any `ON` clause should define the relation between the table name is has followed and preceding result set from a table or joins of tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.match_id, t1.provider_id, t1.visible, t2.match_type, t3.class_num, t3.location_id, t4.prov_name, t6.city_name
    FROM match AS t1 
        JOIN umtc_class AS t2
            on t1.match_id = t2.match_id
        JOIN abroad_class AS t3
            on t1.match_id = t3.match_id
        JOIN provider AS t4
            on t1.provider_id = t4.provider_id  //here was mistake
        JOIN location AS t5
            on t3.location_id = t5.location_id //here was mistake
        JOIN location AS t6
            on t5.city_id = t6.city_id
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using match try using [match] i.e., enclosing match between [ and ]